# Duas aplicações na mesma pasta de aplicação cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3

Eu tenho uma aplicação que possui dois usuarios administradores: um admin para usuários de um sistema de cadastros e outro admin para os administradores do sistema.

Eu gostaria de ter a seguinte estrutura no cakephp3:

> -> pasta principal (é a raiz do site: www.meusite.com)
>
> --> pasta admin1 (sistema de cadastros acessado pelos usuários)
>
> --> pasta admin2 (sistema de administração geral acessado pelo administradores)

Eu gostaria que quando entrar no site (*www.meusite.com*) fosse direcionado para a aplicação da subpasta *"admin1"* (tela de login). Na tela de login, também deixarei disponível um link para os administradores, ou seja, acesso à pasta *"admin2"*.

Claro que os usuários de uma aplicação não podem logar na outra sem estarem devidamente cadastrados.

Como posso fazer isso funcionar no cakephp 3?

Comment: Julio, bem vindo ao SOPT. Acesse a Ajuda e faça o Tour, é importante para tratar as questões aqui.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pelas boas vindas. Farei o tour sim. Obrigado!